# CSV: Replace continuous comma with space

Tags: csv

When there are continuous empty values in csv file, for example, my value is test,,,test3. Here when I replace using the above mentioned function, it replaces only the first occurrence with space test, ,,test3. How to handle the remaining commas? Please help.

Comment: What programming language? Can you share your code?

Comment: The function I used is #[StringUtils.replace(message.payload, ',,',' ')].

Comment: what is your desired output for (test,,,test3)?

Comment: @Mureinik: I am trying to implement using MEL expressions.

Comment: @ZiyadGodil: My Input is test,,,test3 and my output should be as           
 test, , ,test3 (there should be space inbetween the commas)

Comment: @AmalaHariram : you can also do like this Regex.Replace(input, ",", ", ")